# access model from resolveException

Tags: java, spring, file-upload

I'm a beginner with Spring MVC. I'm working on implementing the HandlerExceptionResolver interface in a controller so that it can catch a MaxUploadSizeExceededException. During this exception, I want to redirect the user to the original page, which was a generic view page for a specific record id.

The original id is passed in a model when uploading the file. Yet when it reaches the resolveException method, it seems I no longer have access to that model.

Is there a way to redirect the user to the original view by retrieving the id of the model?

The tricky part with this, it seems, is that this particular type of exception occurs before it reaches the controller. So I can't use a try/catch block within the controller.

Comment: The model is probably still not populated because the exception occurs before the model is built. This is one of those rare scenarios. 
Could you instead use the 'HttpServletRequest' that is passed on to the resolveException() method to access your id?

Comment: It doesn't carry over from the original request. Not sure if there's a way to reset the id in the request...

Comment: Are you using multipart/form-data along with 'POST' in your form? Please post the <form> section of your jsp/html page.

Comment: Yes, it works fine for files under the max file size. It's just when it hits that exception, it creates problems. I found a workaround though. I'm just redirecting the user to a generic error message page with the error message. It's not quite what I wanted, and I'm still open to ideas for ways of redirecting to the original page, but the solution I have now will work.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, I currently redirect the user to a generic error message page when it hits a maxfilesize exception. I will mark this answer as correct for the mean time.